# where to put library folders relative to ActionScript project in FlashBuilder?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

If I create a new ActionScript project with Flash Builder and want to add some library (for example Tweenlite) where do I have to put the gs folder of Tweenlite relative to my project folder? and what do I need to setup in the project settings in order to be able to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't matter, where to put your library folder. Just set the path to this folder at *Project -> Properties -> Flex Build Path -> Library Path -> Add SWC Folder...(or Add SWC)*

Comment: uhm - my bad - it's not a compiled library but folderstructure with .as files

Comment: Then, put it into "src" folder. You can manipulate your sources through the same settings bar as I've already described

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you create a new Library project named something like 'TweenLite' and dump the files in there. Then in Flash Builder go to:

Project -> Properties -> Flex Build Path -> Library path tab -> Add Project -> select the tweenlite project.

In this manner the project's source only gets compiled when it needs to be and the resulting swc is used by your application.  You still get the benefits of the go-to source hotkey and can set breakpoints in the tweenlite project as well.

Cleaner, reusable, faster, it's how I do things.

*Ah also, multiple projects can reference the tweenlite library project now instead of having to copy & paste the code everywhere.